# CommandError: Could not load shell runner: 'IPython Notebook'

Tags: python, django, jupyter-notebook

I'm having an issues starting using jupyter on my system (Mac OSX 14.2.1) even on new django projects.

```bash
django-admin startproject mysite
cd mysite/
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv --python=$(pyenv root)/versions/3.9.18/bin/python3 env
pip install jupyter ipython django-extensions

# add django_extensions to INSTALLED_APPS
vim mysite/settings
python manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

Running the above has the following error:

```
$ python manage.py shell_plus --notebook

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/project/mysite/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py", line 281, in get_notebook
    from notebook.notebookapp import NotebookApp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.notebookapp'

CommandError: Could not load shell runner: 'IPython Notebook'.
```

I have a feeling the answer is something really straightforward, but I've been stuck on this for weeks now and haven't gotten to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently an open issue about this problem on Github since August 2023. Currently there is only a temporarly fix to downgrade the notebook package with: `pip install notebook==6.5.6` After that it worked for me again. See the issue for reference: https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/issues/1835

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. I had to update a number of dependencies:
`pipenv update jupyter-client==8.0.3 jupyter-console==6.5.1 jupyter-core==5.2.0 notebook==6.5.4 traitlets==5.9.0 --dev`